# What Tilaka do the Smartas use?

Tags: tilak, smarta

It is most common to see Smartas with the Tripundra tilakam, but I want a scriptural reference to that.

Comment: Many also use the tantrik " boonda"

Comment: Being a Smarta myself,I don't think so Smarta's are just restricted to Tripundra tilakam(I belong to Maharashtra, maybe Tripundra is famous among South where Lord Shiva is considered Personal God). As According to my Revered Guru, As we practice the Pañcāyatana pūjā we are allowed to apply either the Tripundra(if we consider Lord Shiva as our personal God),Urdhva Pundra (If we consider Lord Narayana), or a single dot between our eyebrows(for Goddess Shakti).

Comment: What Exactly do you want a reference for Sir??

Comment: @Rāmachandra Maybe a reference from a discourse of one of the Shankaracharyas.